# I Cant set a basic HTML template in Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, windows, emmet

so im new in the coding world, i became interested when i had coding classes, last week. In one of them we used Visual Studio Code and i liked the app, it looked relatively easy. But i have some problem with the Emmet,the weird part is that it only doesnt work when im trying to set a basic HTML template using "!". I already tried the settings and the emmet is activated and already tried to edit the setting.json and copied a couple of codes from the internet. Nothing seems to work. Could someone help me?

Comment: Make sure you create an `.html` file when you start ... for instance. `index.html` or `hello.html` - a lot of features in vscode are based on the type of file you are working with.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

1. Open the VSCode settings, search for 'emmet' and scroll down to the 'Emmet: Trigger Expansion on Tab' setting, see [VSCode Emmet Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2fAe.jpg). Make sure it's checked, then close the settings.
2. Create a new file (⌘ N)
3. It should say 'Select a language' at the top
4. Choose HTML
5. Type `!`
6. Press Tab and Emmet should expand it to a basic HTML5 document like

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```